# click event in subscribe method angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have 2 button one of them of type file -which is hidden- if the user click the first button a confirmation dialog opens if user click Ok the second button must be clicked.

The problem is that all the logic is subscribe method -of confirmation dialog - are execute expect clickEvent for the second button.

Can anyone explain why and provide me with a solution?

```
@ViewChild('fileBrowser') fileInput: ElementRef;
dialogRef: MdDialogRef<ConfirmationDialog>;
clickUpload(){
this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialog);
this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
    if (result) {
      // some code
      this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
    }
    this.dialogRef = null;
  });}

   //HTML Code
   <button md-button  (click)="clickUpload()" > upload</button>
   <input #fileBrowser id="fileBrowser" type="file" hidden="true">
```

"this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();"  this is the problem line

Comment: can you add the entire component code? and maybe the html template?

Comment: Put console.log(this.fileInput) to check whether the file element is available or not before click event

Comment: I have add it and it refers to the element i really want

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, i changed dialogRef's method from `afterClosed` to `beforeClose`

The new code

```
this.dialogRef.beforeClose().subscribe((result) => {
if (result) {
  // some code
  this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
}
this.dialogRef = null;
});}
```